# Android camera intent differences

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am developing and application which needs to open camera. I found two different intent to open device camera. But i do not understand what is the difference between them.

Camera intents : 
`

```
android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE

android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same, as specified in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> public static final String ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
>
> Since: API Level 3 Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the
> camera application capture an image and return it. The caller may pass
> an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If
> the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned
> as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications
> that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the
> full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT. See
> Also
>
> EXTRA_OUTPUT
>
> Constant Value: "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"